# Error resolving template [register/save], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers _csft

Tags: postgresql, spring-security, thymeleaf, csrf

I have this error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Dec 15 22:36:23 EST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [register/save], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [register/save], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1373)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1057)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.doFilterInternal(DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:216)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

when trying to access this resource from a redirect from this register.html page with csft protection input field:

```
            <form autocomplete="off" th:action="@{/register/save}" th:object="${userAccount}" method="post" class="form-signin" role="form">
                <h3 class="form-signin-heading">Registration Form</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="">
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{userName}" placeholder="User Name" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="">
                        <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="">
                        <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register User</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- <span th:utext="${successMessage}"></span> -->
            </form>
```

The /register/save resource and the resource of the html is defined in the SecurityController.java like this:

```
@Controller
public class SecurityController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserAccountRepository accountRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptEncoder;
    
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String register(Model model) {
        UserAccount userAccount = new UserAccount();
        model.addAttribute("userAccount", userAccount);
        
        return "security/register";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/register/save")
    public String saveUser(Model model, UserAccount user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        accountRepo.save(user);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

The security Configuration is defined the accesses like this, allowing access to register /save through /** permitAll:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/users/new").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/groups/new").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
    }
```

It would seem that the error was a simple a match error of the controller name (@PostMapping ("/register/save")) and the register.html (th: action = "@ {/register/save}") that invokes it . But I make everything agree. Possibly I need a record or set a TemplateResolver that I haven't used so far. What would I need to verify?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure you are not returning `register/save` as return value from your controller? Because the error that is shown is Thymeleaf searching for `register/save.html` on the classpath and not finding it.

Comment: changed to register/user/ instead of /register/save in the SecurityController class. Same result.

Comment: I meant the return value in the `@GetMapping` annotated method. You have `return "security/register";` there, but the error from Thymeleaf shows `Error resolving template [register/save]`, which would indicate that you have a `@GetMapping` annotated method somewhere that has `return "register/save"`.

Comment: you right @WimDeblaume. I create the save.html in rc/main/resources/templates/register/save.html, and it works. Thanks. By the way, I don't understand why you need some html file to call the PostMapping Method in a controller, that is already there in the calling html file. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you don't fully understand how it works, you might want to read up on [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/).

Answer (score 0):

Looking here: https://www.yawintutor.com/error-1564-error-resolving-template/. Seems there is missing a html file target with the same name of the @PostMapping("/register/save"). I means you need to create a save.html file. Kind of src/main/resources/templates/register/save.html. With this You can execute your PostMapping("/register/save") action in the SecurityController.java from the register.html source calling file.